# Казнить нельзя ,помиловать!

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно понять смысл вот этого предложения с учетом пунктуации ,а именно "**не предусмотренные...**" относится только к испытаниям или ко всему перечислению: "Работы с системами (элементами), важными для безопасности, по выводу в ремонт и вводу в эксплуатацию, а также испытания этих систем (элементов), **не предусмотренные технологическим регламентом безопасной эксплуатации блока АС и инструкциями по эксплуатации**, являются ядерно-опасными."

Answer (score 1):

Здесь, исходя только из синтаксиса и пунктуации однозначно решить нельзя.
По общему смыслу - скорее ко всем трем перечисленным пунктам.
Но это  субъективно. Надо авторов пытать.

Comment: В предыдущей версии документа авторы имели ввиду именно все пункты. А вот теперь на ровном месте создали неопределенность неоднозначности!:-)

Comment: тогда имеет смысл по возможности добиваться устранения неоднозначности.

Comment: Так есть неоднозначность или нет? С точки зрения грамматики, могут основной и присоединительный члены иметь общее определение?

Comment: Не вижу причин, почему не могут.
Конечно, а "так же" несколько затрудняет распространение обшего определения "назад", но формально запрета нет.

Надо образцы такого творчества в законах посмотреть, юристы любят фразы типа "дети, родители, а также внуки, дед и бабка, проживающие совместно с наследодателем..." (пример "от балды"). Ничего, как-то ориентируются.

Comment: А практического примера использования таких конструкций в обычной литературе (не в документах) у Вас не найдется?

Comment: Неужели ж зажал бы, коли бы был?!))))

Comment: И как же доказывают что в "дети, родители, а также внуки, дед и бабка, проживающие совместно с наследодателем..." речь идет о всех детях и родителях, а не только проживающих с наследодателем?)))

Answer (score 0):

Так как грамматическая форма данного предложения, в том числе его пунктуационное оформление, не   имеет однозначного смысла, то это является ошибкой составителей документа.

Если предположить, что все работы, не регламентируемые инструкциями, являются ядерно-опасными, то предложение следует переделать, к примеру, таким образом:

"Работы с системами (элементами), важными для безопасности, по выводу в ремонт и вводу в эксплуатацию, а также испытания этих систем (элементов), являются ядерно-опасными, если они не предусмотрены технологическим регламентом безопасной эксплуатации блока АС и инструкциями по эксплуатации."

И по поводу написания "ядерно-опасный". Дефисная форма  возможна только в том случае, если слово является техническим термином.

Comment: В комментариях к предыдущей редакции документа авторы указывали , что ядерно-опасными работами являются:Работы с системами (элементами), важными для безопасности, по выводу в ремонт и вводу в эксплуатацию;испытания этих систем (элементов) не предусмотреные технологическим регламентом безопасной эксплуатации блока АС и инструкциями по эксплуатации.

Comment: Тогда надо признать, что предложение составлено верно, то есть "не предусмотренные..." относится только к испытаниям. Однозначный смысл предложение имеет в том случае, если мы будем считать, что основной и присоединительный член НЕ МОГУТ ИМЕТЬ общего определения, и поэтому это определение относится  только к присоединительной части. И скорее всего, это именно так.

Comment: Да, хорошо было бы получить экспертное заключение по этому поводу, тогда можно было бы и побороться за истину)